# Potentially ambiguous statement in §9.5/8

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

§9.5/9 from the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> A *union-like class* is a union or a class that has an anonymous union as a direct member. A union-like class `X` has a set of *variant members*. **If `X` is a `union`, a non-static data member of `X` that is not an anonymous union is a variant member of `X`.**

Is the part in bold saying that between a union-like class that is either a class or a union, only if it is a union can it have a non-static variant member that is not an anonymous union? If this is so, why? And what practical difference does it make in code?

I'm actually questioning whether this statement meant to say "If `X` is a *union-like class*...". It would make full sense to me then.

Either way, this clause has been bugging me for the past few days and I wish to fully comprehend what it is stating.

Comment: The "variant member" terminology is related to the concept of a "variant" (e.g. `VARIANT` in Windows). The bolded text is defining *variant member* for the case where `X` is a union. The following sentence (which you didn't quote) defines *variant member* for the case where `X` is not a union, and for the case of anonymous unions that are a member of `X`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your attempted clarification is wrong.  Here is a union-like class X:

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    union {
        double b;
        long c;
    };
};
```

`X::a` is a non-static data member of a union-like class `X` that is not an anonymous union.  But it most definitely is NOT a variant member.

All non-static data members of a union are variant members.  For union-like classes which are not unions, only those nested within union subobjects are variant members.

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain, it takes many years of cognitive damage caused by looking over standards documents, to be able to correctly parse that sort of stuff.

> only if it is a union can it have a non-static variant member that is not an anonymous union?

Not quite.

It's not saying that *only* the union version of a union-like class can have the non-static blah blah blah.

What it's saying is both can *have* it (technically, it's not *saying* that but it's declining to refute the possibility), but only the union version will have it treated as "a variant member of X".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [latest publicly avalable draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) (2013-10-13) have a more refined definition, quote:

> A *union-like class* is a union or a class that has an anonymous union
>   as a direct member. A union-like class X has a set of *variant
>   members*. If `X` is a union, a non-static data member of `X` that is
>   not an anonymous union is a variant member of `X`. In addition, a
>   non-static data member of an anonymous union that is a member of `X`
>   is also a variant member of `X`. At most one variant member of a union
>   may have a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. Example:

```
union U {
    int x = 0;
    union { };
    union {
        int z;
        int y = 1; // error: initialization for second variant member of U
    };
};
```

As for the question, the bolded part is actually defines what is a *variant member*, which a *union-like class* has to have (by having a `union` as a direct member) to be a *union-like class*.

Comment: Umm, that is not the current draft.  Your wording is actually older than the one in the question (which might not be from the C++11 official wording as it claims).